# What is the meaning of Tri-sapta in Atharva-veda?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, atharva-veda

The very first line of Atharva Veda says , "ye trisaptaah pariyanti ...". The meaning of Trisapta here seems somewhat confusing. In the Acharya Vedanta Tirth translation it is called to be the three gunas (satta, rajas, tamas) and seven padarthas (prithvi, jal, tej, vaayu, aakaash,  tanmaatraa, ahamkaara). However, the Sankhya philosophy says that the five tanmaatraas are distinct. Moreover, the other translations do not favor this one, they talk about a much vaster meaning - all the possible permutations of 7 and 3. Can anyone please clear me the real meaning? Moreover, is it somehow related to the corresponding devata Vachaspati? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hope that my answer covered atleast some part which you are expecting.My answer is more scriptural based than philosophical one.And I haven't tried to conclude myself either and left the decision on scholars.If you think that it isn't covering what you exactly required.Pls. let me know about what is your opinion and feel free about it. I will surely try to improve it.

Comment: @Awe Kumar Jha Where can one read your comment about fractal encryption in vedic lieterature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first Sukta of Atharva-Veda is Medha Janan Sukta , Rishi of which is Atharva and Devata is Vachaspati.  This is a prayer to Vāchaspati for divine illumination and help.

> ये **त्रिषप्ता :** परियन्ति विश्वा रूपाणि बिभ्रता : |
>  **वाचस्पतिर्बला**
>   तेषां तन्वो अद्य दधातु मे ||1||
>
> The thrice-seven that go about , bearing all forms - Let the Lord of
>   speech assign to me today their powers [their] selves (tanu).

---

Your main question is about the meaning of the word Tri-Sapta and details about  devata vachaspati.

[**William Dwight Whitney**](https://archive.org/details/atharvavedasamhi01whituoft/page/n169) who   translated Atharva-Veda samhita  with a critical and exegetical commentary  . Revised and brought nearer to completion and edited by Charles Rockwell Lanman says that.

> Tri-Saptas is plainly used as designation of an indefinite number ,=
>   'dozens' or 'scores'  supposing shruti to signify one's acquired
>   sacred knowledge , portion of shruti.
>
> First he conjectures that it may mean ' three or seven ' ; as the
>   three worlds , the three gunas  three highest gods  ; or sevan seers ,
>   the seven planets , the seven troops od Maruts , the seven worlds ,
>   the seven meters or the like. Secondarily , it may mean ' three sevens
>   ' as seven suns (for which is quoted TA. i.7.1) and seven priests and
>   seven Adityas (TA. i.13.3 ; RV. ix.114.3) , or seven rivers , sevan
>   worlds and seven quarters (TB. ii.8.3.) or seven planets ,seven seers
>   and seven  marut troops . Thirdly it may signify simply thrice seven
>   or twenty-one as twelve months +five seasons +three worlds +one sun
>   (TS.vii.3.105) or five Mahabhutas +five breaths + five jnanendriyas
>   +five karmendriyas + one antahkarana . At any rate they are the gods ,who are to render aid.

---

[**Shripad Damodar Satwalekar**](https://archive.org/details/AtharvavedaSubodhBhashya/page/n47) in his commentary " Atharvaveda Subodh Bhashya " is mentioning that

> The original seven elements in their three forms are everywhere and
>   their flow and transformation is giving shape to this universe.

So these are original twenty one elements which are also inside our body , our goal is to maintain harmony of these twenty one elements which are inside to twenty one elements outside to  live a healthy life with sound mind power and this is the core topic of Atharva-Veda.

---

Author [**Shree Ram Sharma Acharya**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/atharveda/v1.17) is also saying similarly  like William Dwight , he says.

> The majority of commentators has concluded the meaning of Tri-Sapta as
>   3*7 =21 . But the view of the seer is much more wider than that.
>   Tri-Sapta can be explained  according to  permutations maths as 3+7
>   =10 , 3*7=21 , seven raise to three 343 ,three raise to 729 etc.  The seer has written the word Tri-Sapta as one so the meaning of it is all
>   the possible combinations i.e.(Tri-Sapta). On this basis  the covers 
>   three worlds ,three gunas , three dimensions , three devas etc. In
>   this way there can be infinite permutations and combination are
>   possible and only Vachaspati knows them all.

---

## Vachaspati.

The devata of this sukta is Vachaspati various acharyas as well as authors have presented their views about  possible meaning of Vachaspati

[**Shree Ram Sharma  Acharya**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/atharveda/v1.17) in his commentary on first sukta of Atharva-Veda  is explaining the meaning of the term in following way.

> According to him Parabrahman covers all this universe all the time in
>   his unmanifested form  (Avyakta अव्यक्त). But when he expresses
>   himself from unmanifested to manifested , then its appropriate to call
>   him "Vachaspati".

---

[**Shripad Damodar Satwalekar**](https://archive.org/details/AtharvavedaSubodhBhashya/page/n47) in his commentary " Atharvaveda Subodh Bhashya " is also explaining this devta he is stating that .

> Who is Vachaspati? Vak , Vani , Vaktrutva ,upadesh , Vyakhyan are
>   related words. The person who is a excellent in speech i.e. a very
>   good Guru (teacher) who is good  counsellor is Vachaspati

So from the above two passages the Devata Vachaspati is a good Guru or Supreme Brahman in his manifested form.

Comment: @SwiftPuskar Following the Rig Vedic tradition 3×7 is correct meaing as counting there appears mostly in conjugation apart from 1to 10,20,30....100.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

As the above clip from the Sanskrit scholar William D. Whitney shows, the meaning of "triSapta = 3x7 (Monnier-Williams)" seems not to be a well-defined term.

I consider plausible Whitney's conjecture to take "triSapta" as an indefinite numeral. The verse is a prayer to Vacaspati, the god of speech, and opens the whole work. The prayer is followed by a series of hymns. Therefore I do not expect that the verses allude to technical terms from the Indian philosophical schools.

Comment: I have pointed the same thing, the uncertainty of meaning , in my question too , in that case, you seem to give just a reference to justify the question itself. Anyway, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Tri sapta describes the entire Hindu universe. It has two words - tri that is 3 and sapta or 7.

One proposed interpretation is the 3 are the planes of existence - bhur, bhuvah, svah - the 3 worlds. The earth, sky and everything in between.

The 7 are senses. The 5 elemental senses - sight, taste, hearing, touch and smell. The other are Proprioception, sense of knowing the motion of parts of your own body eg being able to clap hands with eyes closed, and balance or internal body senses.

So trisapta is all 7 senses in all 3 planes, which covers the entire universe.

Comment: Hi, please add the reference in your answer which is mandatory on this site.